# Retrieving Data from multiple tables from Database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have some tables in a database. They have some particular pattern. For example, consider I have table employee, then some other table with same pattern like:

```
table 1:employee
table 2:employee_X
table 3:employee_Y
```

I want to check if these tables contain data or not and if they do then I have to call some method for each table. I am using following code to retrieve.

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, "My_Table_Name", new String[] {"TABLE"});
while (res.next()) {

    if(rs.getStrin(3).equals(employee)){
        //my code to write data of this table to a file
    }

    if(rs.getString(3).equals(employee_X)){
        //my code to write data to the same file

    }

    if(rs.getString(3).equals(employee_Y)){
        //code to write data to the same file from this table
    }
}
```

The code is working fine, but how I can retrieve data from all these tables at once instead of using three checks. If any of these table contains data I want to write it to my file. How I can perform this operation in less lines of code and efficiently?

It would be great if anyone can suggest way to check each of these table either contain data or not in a single statement and then I can call my code to write data to file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` statement in your complex query. Please, check example:

```
SELECT id, name FROM employee WHERE id = ?
    UNION
SELECT id, name FROM employee_x WHERE id = ?
    UNION
...
```

Also you can use `UNION ALL` statement instead of `UNION`. The main difference that `UNION` returns unique result set without duplicates, `UNION ALL` allows duplicates. Please, check this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp for detailed explanation about `union` statement.

If you need create `UNION` query with custom filtered tables, please check example:

```
Set<String> requiredTables = new HashSet<>();
// fill set with required tables for result query
requiredTables.add("employee");
ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, "My_Table_Name", 
 new String[] {"TABLE"});

List<String> existentTables = new LinkedList<>();
while(res.next()) {
    if (requiredTables.contains(res.getString(3)) {
        existentTables.add(res.getString(3)); 
    }
}

String query = existentTables.stream().map(table -> String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", table)).collect(Collectors.joinning(" UNION "));
```

Comment: nops first I want my code should search if it databse contains a particular table or not and if contains then retireve data from it. thats why I have to use if statement again and again

Comment: In this case, you can get available tables from db, then filter required and create single query with union as defined in the answer.

Comment: thats what I am asking how to filter tables of a particular pattern in one go

Comment: For example, if you have list of all table names in db: `List<String> tables`, you can generate sql query: `tables.stream().filter(predicate).map(t -> "select * from " + t").collect(Collectors.joining(" UNION "))`.

Comment: hey I didn't got your code..could you please explain in detail

Comment: And in your code suppose same three tables I have for students and many other tables but all tables will be in this form as mentioned for employees.  For example similarly I can have 3 tables for student then again three tables for something else.. Than I want to take one by one each pair and write data to my files.  Suppose can I take all three employee tables at once and write data and then all three student tables should come and then I have to write data of all 3 student table in one file.. Is this is possible?

Comment: It's doesn't matter how many tables you have. You should collect data from them in one query, I described you approach how you can do that. In similar way, you can filter other group of tables and create query with `UNION` statement. After data collected from the tables you can store it where you want. Yes, it's possible.

Comment: can you please explain above mentioned sq query. It would be very helpful for me to know how this query works

Comment: Please, check provided link in the answer.